# using await in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

I am trying to do an async function in c#. I was able to get it using this code:

```
private async Task loadData()
{
     try
     {
         await Task.Run(() => { testTableAdapter.Fill(testDataSet.tbl); });
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

But since I am trying to access UI controls, I tried to do it without doing a Task.Run (so I don't start a new worker thread), and I am getting an error that I don't understand or how to fix.

```
private async Task loadData()
{
     try
     {
          await  testTableAdapter.Fill(testDataSet.tbl); 
          perComboBox.text = loadedSearch.toString();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1061  'int' does
>   not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method
>   'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well it looks like the problem is in the `// code` bit that you omitted. It's unclear what you're really trying to do here, without more context.

Comment: its a dataset fill, I edited the OP. sorry!

Comment: Right, so the problem is that that's a *synchronous* operation. You can't use async/await to magically make synchronous operations asynchronous. Now where in that code are you trying to access UI controls?

Comment: its simply changing the value of a combobox text, but the error happens on the await. Is there anyway to have a dataset fill asynchronously that you know of?

Comment: *What* is changing the value of the combobox? Is this a combobox which is bound to the datatable? Perhaps you should unbind, fill, then rebind...

Comment: Just put the UI code after the `await Task.Run`. Why did you remove `Task.Run` at all? It will only run its *delegate* in a pooled thread, not the subsequent code. In fact, no new thread will be created unless the thread pool is already empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. Please read more of what Stephen Cleary's home page has to offer. Thread and Background Worker are obsolete when using async. Depending on where you consume `LoadData` it's always a good idea to provide a synchronous method. You can then wrap it into an async one depending on implementation. You should really be getting back your TableAdaper results from a proper DataAccessLayer. Remember separation of concerns.

Change your method to:

```
private int LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        return testTableAdapter.Fill(testDataSet.tbl); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Now the async wrapper in your calling class. Really the async part should be inside of a window load or other GUI event. Here is an example of a button click that would fill your data. The `.ConfigureAwait(false)` indicates that the awaiter will be send to the scheduler instead of executing on the GUI thread. Also consider using MVVM for WPF. I would like to note that the _cToken's CancellationTokenSource gets set to Cancel() should your Window_Closing event be called. This is to make sure your async operation gets cleaned up.

```
private async void _btnTruck_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        count = await Task.Run(() => LoadData(), _cToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        perComboBox.text = loadedSearch.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, got an error on cancellationToken, saying 'CancellationToken' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Try passing in `CancellationToken.None` rather than just `CancellationToken`

Comment: The code example assumes you have a property named `CancellationToken` on your form

Comment: Keep in mind, if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` you cannot do anything else to the UI after that call. So, for example, if you wanted to use `perComboBox.text = loadedSearch.toString();` as in the question, you can't now.

Comment: .ConfigureAwait() defines where the awaiter is maintained. True means calling thread maintains it and false means its sent to the scheduler. It will not restrict interaction with the GUI if it is set to false. Consider that if your GUI thread is overloaded and then the async code is called it must then maintain the awaiter as well putting additional strain on it to keep track of the synchronization objects under the covers.